# mvvm general doubts and messageBox

Tags: c#, mvvm

I am developing a `WPF` application with the `MVVM` pattern.

I know that the `MVVM` pattern is good to seprate the `GUI` and the logic of the application, so I can test the `GUI` and the logic independently.

However, if I need to send some messages to the user, is it a good idea to use a messageBox or not? Because I am reading about some solutions, all of them try to implement a new view a its view model... etc. But I don't see very well the utility.

I mean that if I want to notify something to the user, my results depends on the decision of the user, how can I separate my tests (GUI and logic)? What is the benefit of not using directly a messageBox instead a new view with the viewmodel and all the extra work that this requiered? Because in both cases my results depends of the user decision. How can I test my application in this case?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> Because I am reading about some solutions, all of them try to
>   implement a new view a its view model... etc. But I don't see very
>   well the utility.

How do you unit test a method which is opening message boxes?

What if the specification changes and you need to use a different (custom) message box, or even only log an error (to be displayed in a summary report later on)? Then you need to find and replace each and every `msgBox.Show` call.

> I mean that if I want to notify something to the user, my results
>   depends on the decision of the user, how can I separate my tests (GUI
>   and logic)?

By creating an event, which is triggered when you need a decision to be made. Then you're getting the decision back. You don't care where it came from.

> Because in both cases my results depends of the user decision. How can
>   I test my application in this case?

Very simply. You just mock your user reply. You can (and probably should) test both possible scenarioes, so just attach two "fake" event handlers: one returning positive decision, one returning negative decision, as if your user actually clicked "Yes" or "No" in some messagebox.

See http://joyfulwpf.blogspot.com/2009/05/mvvm-communication-among-viewmodels.html for example.

**ASpirin**'s suggestion of injecting a notifier is also a good design choice.

Some sketchy, oversimplified implementation:

```
using System;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace Demo
{
    public delegate bool DecisionHandler(string question);
    /// <remarks>
    /// Doesn't know a thing about message boxes
    /// </remarks>    
    public class MyViewModel
    {
        public event DecisionHandler OnDecision;

        private void SomeMethod()
        {
            // something...

            // I don't know who or what replies! I don't care, as long as I'm getting the decision!
            // Have you made your decision for Christ?!! And action. ;)
            var decision = OnDecision("Do you really want to?"); 

            if (decision)
            {
                // action
            }
            else
            {
                // another action
            }
        }
    }

    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            // this ViewModel will be getting user decision from an actual message box
            var vm = new MyViewModel();
            vm.OnDecision += DecideByMessageBox;

            // unlike that one, which we can easily use for testing purposes
            var vmForTest = new MyViewModel();
            vmForTest.OnDecision += SayYes;    
        }        

        /// <summary>
        /// This event handler shows a message box
        /// </summary>        
        static bool DecideByMessageBox(string question)
        {
            return MessageBox.Show(question, String.Empty, MessageBoxButtons.YesNo) == DialogResult.Yes;
        }
        /// <summary>
        /// Simulated positive reply
        /// </summary>        
        static bool SayYes(string question)
        {
            return true;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

In any case of usage, you may create Notifier class (wich implements your interface (e.x. `IUserNotifier{ void ShowMessage(string message);}` or maybe more complex)), who will show message box. And use other implementation for testing, which display nothing and just return result. When you'll create specific styled view, another implementation will show it